# Visual Studio Code going down to line automatically

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code, brackets

I am using Brackets at the moment i want to switch to Visual Stuido Code but some features of Brackets are very usefull.

One of them, i use the editor narrowly, Brackets going under line automatically if it is not fit the line, but Visual Studio Code does not.

And second one also is when i design a html i can see the differences in live preview, is it possible to see it in Visual Stuido Code also?

[Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59NGF.png)

[Brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLqBJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to enable the Word Wrap in Visual Studio Code.
Go to View -> Toggle Word Wrap.

Live Preview is actually possible in every editor you use. Today's devs use task automators like Gulp or Grunt, so they are not attached to specific editor like Brackets.

Using Gulp (or Grunt) you can set up a task that will watch your files for changes and then do specific actions, like reload the page, recompile Sass files etc.

You can find more here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5fvdIa0ETk

Comment: Thanks for your answer